# How to Error Check an entire column in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

So my boss needs me to Error Check a Form.  When you click on the button the user should be in the first column before adding any information, if not then it needs to display an error message telling them that they need to be in the first column before getting started.  We have been using ActiveCell.Offset to insert data automatically and if you start in any other column besides the first one, the information is off by one cell.

Here is my error code for this. This code is in the form itself and I need to call it in the module  that is required for this program.  Any help wold be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub Error_Check()
If Not Range(A1, [A1,048,576]) Then
        MsgBox ("Please make sure you are in the Product Attribute Set column before proceeding.")
    Else
        ConfigGroup.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't rely on where the active cell is to work properly (most likely). Is it not possible to specifically identify where the new insertions should go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions.

1. Instead of the code referencing the active cell, reference the first column, i.e. `SheetName.Columns(1)`
2. If you prefer to keep the code based off of `ActiveCell.Offset`, why not have the macro select a cell in the first column for the user? For example, insert `Cells(1,1).Select` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: The only instance where this wouldn't work as stated is if they needed the row the user had selected as well, but that would be a trivial addition.

Comment: So I have a module called ConfigGroupForm that shows the form when the button is clicked.  I need the error check to run as the button is clicked so how would I call a sub from a form and put it into a module

Comment: 'Public Sub ConfigGroupForm()
    ConfigGroup.Error_Check
End Sub'